# Dovecot, postfix - can't receive any emails to my server

Tags: server

I have problem with my postfix or dovecot. i'm trying to create a mail server with postfix, dovecot, roundcube.

but i can send mail to my gmail, but i can't send from gmail to my server.

inside my (**/etc/postfix/main.cf**)

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = domain.com
mydomain = domain.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_interfaces = localhost
#mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 xx.xx.xx.xx/26
#relayhost = 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
recipient_delimiter =
#home_mailbox = Maildir/
home_mailbox =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/sbin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/sbin/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
readme_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
message_size_limit = 25600000
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d

biff = no

# Virtual domains, users, and aliases 

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_maps  = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual/addresses

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/ssl/mailserver.csr
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/ssl/mailserver.pem
smtpd_use_tls=no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_client_restrictions =

#Enabling SMTP for authenticated users. 

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   permit_mynetworks,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023n

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks
   permit_sasl_authenticated
   reject_unknown_sender_domain
   reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
   reject_unknown_client_hostname
   #check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_unauth_destination

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
compatibility_level = 2
mailbox_size_limit = 0
```

i have looked in (**tail -f /var/log/mail.log**) error here:

```
Aug  6 14:18:20 hvass dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<postmaster@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=1818, secured, session=<uq/80XGPwLkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Aug  6 14:18:20 hvass dovecot: imap(postmaster@domain.com): Debug: Effective uid=5000, gid=5000, home=/var/mail/vhosts/domain.com/postmaster
Aug  6 14:18:20 hvass dovecot: imap(postmaster@domain.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/domain.com/postmaster
Aug  6 14:18:20 hvass dovecot: imap(postmaster@domain.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/mail/vhosts/domain.com/postmaster, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/mail/vhosts/domain.com/postmaster, alt=
Aug  6 14:18:20 hvass dovecot: imap(postmaster@domain.com): Logged out in=50 out=490
```

I have looked in my logs, and i can't see nothing.

And i have open port: (https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html)

Can someone help me with that? Thanks :)

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 15:58**

I'm trying to telnet got this error:

```
Frederiks-MacBook-Pro:~ frederikfrandsen$ telnet domain.com 25
Trying 100.68.184.44...
telnet: connect to address 100.68.184.44: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 16:07**

i run this command:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix

Now i can telnet to my server:

```
Frederiks-MacBook-Pro:~ frederikfrandsen$ telnet domain.com 25
Trying 100.68.184.44...
Connected to domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 domain.com ESMTP Postfix
```

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 16:29**

i send a telnet to my server but google gmail got this error here:

```
host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.127.26] said:
550-5.7.1 [185.107.12.164      11] Our system has detected that this
message is 550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant: 550-5.7.1 'From' header is
missing. 550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message
has been 550-5.7.1 blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant 550 5.7.1 and
review RFC 5322 specifications for more information. f20si30711503edy.431 -
gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 16:50**

Sorry i was on my local network thats why telnet works.

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 17:51**

It was my firewall / port forwarding. now it works :)

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 19:51**

it works now, new problem i can't send from gmail to my server. have any idea why?

**Edit 6/07-2019 - 20:11**

I'm trying to connect to (telnet domain.com 25):

> Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname

**Edit 7/07-2019 - 12:01**

I was my dns serer i wait to day and now it works 100% :)

**Edit 8/07-2019 - 18:15**

I got new qustion, i can't send email from iphone to www

> fatal: invalid "-o smtpd_client_restrictions" option value: missing
>   '=' after attribute name

**Edit 8/07-2019 - 19:08**

the logs shows:

```
Aug  8 19:05:40 hvass postfix/submission/smtpd[11525]: lost connection after EHLO from unknown[185.107.12.164]
Aug  8 19:05:40 hvass postfix/submission/smtpd[11525]: disconnect from unknown[185.107.12.164] ehlo=1 commands=1
Aug  8 19:05:55 hvass postfix/submission/smtpd[11525]: connect from unknown[185.107.12.164]
```

**Edit 8/07-2019 - 19:24**

> telnet: could not resolve domain.com/25: Name or service not known

**Edit 8/07-2019 - 20:27**

i got: Relay access denied use
**https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%domain.com&run=toolpage#**

**Edit 9/07-2019 - 14:00**

i'm useing: https://www.wormly.com/test-smtp-server

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem
SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem
2019-08-09 11:57:38 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Can some one help me? i have tls on my server.

**Edit 9/07-2019 - 15:23**

i got new error:

> dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (tried to use disallowed plaintext
>   auth)

**Edit 9/07-2019 - 16:24**

i edit the file here:

> /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf
>   edit too -> disable_plaintext_auth = no

And it works now on my iphone !

But don't works on android !

can someone tell me why?

Comment: This question should belong to serverfault